# Sound and keys on chromebook (Asus c200)

Tags: keyboard, audio, asus, chromebook

I am running Elementary OS on a chromebook (Asus c200). The performance is great, but I do not have sound, nor the "function" keys work as intended (reload, brightness, full screen, etc).

Is there a solution to this?

I've followed the this steps regarding the sound, but with no success:
https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you...

http://www.fascinatingcaptain.com/projects/remap-keyboard-keys-for-ubuntu/

Good Luck